# Change url on runtime (i.e. rewrite url)

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewrite-module

I want to rewrite my website url through the htaccess, currently my project made in YII, i want to change my url on runtime.

currently this is not on live server, this is on my local server and my current password is

```
localhost/pecb_new/trunk/admin/apps/backend/site/login
```

and i want to change it to

```
localhost/pecb_new/trunk/admin/site/login
```

i.e. change admin/apps/backend/ from url to the `admin/`, please if some one has answer of this question then provide me the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting these rules in the htaccess file in the `/trunk/admin/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+trunk/admin/apps/backend/([^\ \?]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/trunk/admin/apps/backend/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/trunk/admin/apps/backend/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /trunk/admin/apps/backend/$1 [L]
```